# ASP DropdownList selected index changing after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have this problem concerning asp `DropDownList`. My `DropDownList` contains many `ListItem` with different texts but some may have the same value.

Now whenever I select an item in the `DropDownList` and click a button to save, the selected Index changes to a different index. I realize that the new selected Index changed to usually have the same value as the index I selected in the first place.

```
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNature_of_Business" runat="server" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="SELECT"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="BDC / MFB"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Money Transmitter"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Money Transmitter"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Leather Goods Store"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Car Dealer"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Travel Agency"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Jewel & Gem Dealer"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Imports/Exports"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Cash Intensive Business-Restaurants"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Cash Intensive Business-Retail Stores"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Cash Intensive Business-Furnished apartments"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Cash Intensive Business-Hotels"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Cash Intensive Business-etc"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Govt Contractors"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Weapons & Arms Dealers"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Charity Organizations"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="NGOs"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Professional Service Provider - Lawyer"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Professional Service Provider - Accountant"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Professional Service Provider - etc"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Manufacturing"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Construction"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Others"></asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Whenever I select `Car Dealer`, it changes to `BDC / MFB`, `NGOs` changes to `Charity Organizations` while `Construction` changes to `Manufacturing`

From my observation, the selected index changes to to the first `ListItem` with the same value as the selected `ListItem`

I've tried using HTML `<select></select>` instead but it still behaves the same even on different browsers.

The only solution I could think of now is to remove the `Value` attribute from the `ListItem` and use only the `Text` attribute. Then I'll save all the `DropDownList` Items in a table and write a C# method that gets their values using the SelectedItem's Text. But then I have over 30 more of `DropDownList` like this one but with different group of `ListItem`.

Does anybody knows a better workaround?

Comment: I don´t know why you have a dropdown list with duplicated values? you get this list from database or you populate it directly? one of the things that you can use is to save as text and select the item in the dropdown list based on text dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: I only get the correct selected index if I don't specify the value attribute. Even with dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text, it still gives me a different index.

Comment: You populate the dropdown list from database?

Comment: I've tried populating this one from the db but I still get the same behavior. So I removed the value attribute just like i said in the question and used a c# method to get the values from the db.

Comment: I just thought there could be a workaround the duplicate values

Comment: You need to set the value as Id value to be unique or you can use a method to get the index of the item based on the item text after populate the dropdown list

Comment: I don't get it "set the value as Id value"

Comment: Yes if you get this list from database it must be a primary key in the table, so use this column as value in the driopdown list and you get a different value for each option

Comment: Oh, yes. The thing is I also need the values for some computations before saving to the database.

Comment: You can create a dictionary by saving the primary key and the value, but publish the primary key in the dropdown list. This way will make your code hard to maintain and you will have problems if there are more option added to the dropdown list

Comment: I think, I will just populate only the text from the database on the dropdownlist without the values since the text is always unique. Then I'll write a method to get the values from the db and use the values for my computation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125628/discussion-between-mbadeveloper-and-ahmad-tijani).